# Linux directory structure for new application

Tags: 16.04, python, python3, directory-structure

I am writing a new Python application that I intend to distribute to several colleagues. Instead of my normal carefree attitude of just having everything self contained and run inside a folder in my home directory, this time I would like to broaden my horizon and actually try to utilize the Linux directory structure as it was intended (at least somewhat). Can you please read my breakdown below and comment and or make recommendations if this is not correct.

Lets call the program "narf"

```
/usr/narf - Install location for the actual python file(s).    
/usr/bin/narf - Either a softlink to the main python file above or use this location instead.    
/etc/narf - Any configuration files for app narf.    
/var/log/narf - Any log files for app narf.    
/usr/lib - Any required libraries for app narf.    
/run/narf - Any persistent (across reboot), but still temp files for app narf.    
/tmp/narf - Very temp files for app narf that go away with reboot
```

I assume I should stick to using /usr/X (for example /usr/bin instead of just /bin) since my application is not system critical and a mere addon.

I currently use 16 LTS, however part of this is intend as a way to try to standardize my app for any popular Linux distro.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem that you may have is `/run` directory. It is also used as temporary storage and is recommended for privileged processes only. Thus, files stored there are not persistent, as you intend them to be, and will be gone with a reboot.

Depending on the purpose of those persistent files, you might store temp data in user's `~/.local/share/narf` directory if that data is user-specific, or use `/var/cache/narf` (or `/var/tmp` , since it's supposed to be persistent according to [Wikipedia's breakdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)) for persistent data.

Comment: Ok great. I don't officially have a need for those temp directories yet. Just wanted to outline their use case in the event that I did need them. Can you comment on the use of /usr/bin vs just /usr? Also whether I should use /usr at all, or just stick with system wide /bin? Thanks

Comment: @Atomiklan  stick to `/usr/bin`.  All 3rd party,non-essential binaries go there

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/narf - Install location for the actual python file(s).`

Don't. Packages don't create top-level directories in `/usr` for themselves. If these are Python files for use by your application, put them somewhere in `/usr/share/narf`, which is for architecture-independent files used by package narf. For example, terminator and `/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/translation.py`.

If you're not creating a package, then everything in `/usr` moves to `/usr/local` (so `/usr/local/bin/narf`, `/usr/local/share/narf`, etc.).